# cheap low light display for PI

Tags: display, composite-video

I'm trying to build a dual-head alarm clock with a raspberry pi (1 pi, 2 display/button stations, 1 for each side of the bed).  I was planning on using a pair of these off the composite port:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00IUGW7PM/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IUGW7PM)

but the LCD puts out too much light even with an all black screen to be used as an alarm clock.  The ideal display would be some sort of OLED-type display where I can turn the brightness down to the point that you couldn't even read it in a well lit room (my wife wants our bedroom absolutely pitch black).  It also needs to be something alarm-clock sized, so a least 1 inch tall and 3 inch wide.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [PiTFT](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1983) from Adafruit which connects directly to your GPIO. There is an option to turn off the display via a tactical button. I own one and love it.

[image: PiTFT - Adafruit]